# The term 'Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: azure-functions, powershell-7.2

I'm using a Azure Function with the following powershell script

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$WorkspaceName = $Request.Query.WorkspaceName
if (-not $WorkspaceName) {
    $WorkspaceName = $Request.Body.WorkspaceName
}
$PipelineName = $Request.Query.PipelineName
if (-not $PipelineName) {
    $PipelineName = $Request.Body.PipelineName
}

$body = "Random text"

# if ($name) {
#     $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
# }

Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -PipelineName $PipelineName 

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
Message : The term 'Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
                      Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've already went to app_files in the function app and uncomment the the following line in the `requirements.psd1` and its like that:

```
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
     'Az' = '9.*'
}
```

How can i make Azure read correctly the `Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline` command? Also i'm using powershell 7.2 in the function App

Comment: `Install-Module -Name Az.Synapse` - Add this line to the script after $body variable or install it in that project terminal. Also, mention `'Az.Synapse' = '0.10.0'` in the `requirements.psd`` and then check.

Comment: This will install this dependency only in this function or in the all the functions apps?

Comment: If you write this `Install-Module ...` in the Function script and module name with version in requirements.psd1, then that module will be installed in that specific azure function project

Comment: i'm getting error 500, gonna try to restart the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created Azure Functions PowerShell Language - Basic Http Trigger and modified the code according to your requirement and working as expected.

**run.ps1**:

```
using  namespace  System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host  "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$WorkspaceName = $Request.Query.WorkspaceName
if (-not $WorkspaceName) {
$WorkspaceName = $Request.Body.WorkspaceName
}

$PipelineName = $Request.Query.PipelineName
if (-not $PipelineName) {
$PipelineName = $Request.Body.PipelineName
}  

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($WorkspaceName && $PipelineName) {
$body = "Hello Krishna, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -PipelineName $PipelineName

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body

})
```

**requirements.psd1**:

```
@{
'Az' = '9.*'
'Az.Synapse' = '0.10.0'
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Note: *Part of the above code taken from the MS Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/invoke-azsynapsepipeline?view=azps-9.2.0) references.*

Comment: So i'm using something similar to that but i'm getting some permissions error and now i'm trying to find a way to pass the credentials to the power shell code

Comment: I have modified the code and posted it. Please check with my code.

Comment: I saw it but i'm running on an Azure Function and it seems that they cant get the credentials i'm trying to run `Connect-AzAccount ` and `Select-AzSubscription` but i keep getting this erro `[Error]   ERROR: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:8400/ for the system browser to complete the login.`

Comment: Are you running it on cloud or locally?

Comment: On cloud, i'm running this power shell script inside a Azure Function in the "test/run" tab

Comment: As you didn't mention it in the question, I have tested it on locally. Let me test in Portal and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, for that

Comment: @GabrielPadilha, Could you please accept it as answer and raise a new question for the same issue having when running in the cloud so that it would get more attention from the other community members, and I will address there with clear details regarding the script running in the cloud.

Comment: Here's the new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824936/azure-function-getting-this-error-no-default-subscription-has-been-designated-u