# Azure Function getting this error No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzSubscription -Default <subscriptionName>

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

So I'm running the following PowerShell script in the Azure Function console on the tab `test/run`

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$WorkspaceName = $Request.Query.WorkspaceName
if (-not $WorkspaceName) {
$WorkspaceName = $Request.Body.WorkspaceName
}

$PipelineName = $Request.Query.PipelineName
if (-not $PipelineName) {
$PipelineName = $Request.Body.PipelineName
}  

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($WorkspaceName && $PipelineName) {
$body = "Hello Gabriel, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -PipelineName $PipelineName

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body

})
```

My requirements.psd1 file is like that:

```
@{
    'Az.Synapse' = '0.10.0'
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.2.3'
}
```

And i'm getting the following error during the test/run of the function

```
[Error] ERROR: No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
```

I tried some fix to connect to get the credentials but I'm really noob regarding IAM, credentials etc. in the cloud

Comment: So, did you try `Select-AzSubscription -Default <subscriptionName>`?

Comment: Yep and i got this error `ERROR: Cannot bind parameter 'DefaultProfile'. Cannot convert the "My subscripton name of the body" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer".`

Answer (score 1):

I have created the Azure Synapse workspace and the Pipeline where a recurrence trigger is defined for every 15 minutes.
Created the Azure Functions PowerShell 7.2 (Http Trigger) and modified the code according to your requirement of Invoking the Azure Synapse Workspace Pipeline:

**run.ps1**:

```
using  namespace  System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)  

Write-Host  "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

Connect-AzAccount -DeviceCode
Set-AzContext -Subscription '<your_subscription_id>'

$WorkspaceName = $Request.Query.WorkspaceName
if (-not $WorkspaceName) {
$WorkspaceName = $Request.Body.WorkspaceName
}

$PipelineName = $Request.Query.PipelineName
if (-not $PipelineName) {
$PipelineName = $Request.Body.PipelineName
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."  

Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -PipelineName $PipelineName

if ($WorkspaceName && $PipelineName) {
$body = "Hello Krishna, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body
})
```

When you run the Function URL in another tab of the browser and observe the log stream of the Function App, you'll receive the device login code such as below format:

[image]

You have to open the [device login URL](https://microsoft.com/devicelogin) and enter the code provided to login & set the default subscription for the current context and then the final result would be like below:

**Result**:

[image]

In the same run.ps1 code, if you change the connecting Az Account Format such as:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant  '<Your_Tenant_Id>' -SubscriptionId  'Your_Subscription_Id'
Set-AzContext -Subscription '<Your_Subscription_Id>'
```

**Result**:
[image]

Note: *Part of the above code taken from the MS Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/invoke-azsynapsepipeline?view=azps-9.2.0).*

Comment: I'm having some problems autenticating my device, but it's company policy. There is another way to autenticate or get the credentials that is not by mobile DeviceCode?

Comment: Instead of device code, try with the `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant -Subscription` given at the end of an above answer

Comment: I keep getting this error `[Error]   ERROR: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost` maybe it has something to do with the firewall of the company

Comment: My solution was change the synapse trigger to a storage event trigger and use the logic app to create a blob to trigger this new trigger. Also the problem was that my Synapse uses private endopoints and the azure function communicate with synapse outside of my trusted vnet